# In opencv,It's too slow by use Mat type to calculate the Mahalanobis distance. How can i improve the efficiency？

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

```
Mat imv;
Mat_<double>end(1, 1);
double distance;
Mat_<double>Point(1, 3);     
...
imv = Point.t();
end = Point*inv[m]*imv;
distance = sqrt(end(0, 0));
```

there is the definition of the variable type and the calculation process of mahalanobis distance.

Comment: What was your question? What benchmarks have you measured? What platform are you using? Please try a little harder if you would like some help!

Comment: Sorry about lack of details.I try to calculate the Mahalanobis distance between data(Point)  and color model(inv[m] is the color m 's covariance matrix )    I calculate the distance between every pixel in ROI and color model to classfication the pixel. When I run the code, it is spend much time in" end = Point*inv[m]*imv"  .I want to know how to optimize this part.Is it because of the  type is Mat?

Comment: There's still no [mcve], nor any evidence of any measurements being done.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry about the expression is not clear.I try to traverse every pixel in the image, calculate the Mahalanobis distance between them and the color model and is too slow.I've always thought that optimization should be done from the efficiency of matrix multiplication.Today I improve the efficiency by use Multi-threaded to improve circulation speed and it is useful.

```
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(6)
            for (int m = 0; m < k_num; m++) {       
                Mat_<double>end(1, 1);
                double distance = 1000;
                Mat_<double>Point(1, 3);
                 Point(0, 0) = double(data3[j * 3]) - mean1[m].at<double>(0, 0);
                Point(0, 1) = double(data3[j * 3 + 1]) - mean1[m].at<double>(0, 1);
                Point(0, 2) = double(data3[j * 3 + 2]) - mean1[m].at<double>(0, 2);

                end = Point * inv[m] * Point.t();
                distance = sqrt(end(0, 0));
                }
            }
```